# Redshift JDBC vs ODBC drivers performance

Tags: jdbc, odbc, amazon-redshift

To connect to the AWS Redshift we can use JDBC or ODBC drivers. Recently I have heard that the JDBC drivers performance is about 40% better than ODBC ones. Unfortunately, I cannot find such information somewhere in the documentation.

Do you have any experiences which drivers perform better on AWS Redshift?

Comment: As far as i know, JDBC and ODBC both performance are same and i didn't see any difference.

Answer (score 3):

There may be minor differences in query execution time for different driver types due to the following:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_challenges_achieving_high_performance_queries.html#compiled-code

> The execution engine compiles different code for the JDBC connection protocol and for ODBC and psql (libq) connection protocols, so two clients using different protocols will each incur the first-time cost of compiling the code. Other clients that use the same protocol, however, will benefit from sharing the cached code.

Note that first time compilation cost has been dramatically reduced in recent Redshift releases.